# Task Scheduler using C# (To Schedule .bat(batch) file)

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I want to create one Task Scheduler using C# same as Windows Task Scheduler, to run my .bat (batch) file on particular time.

I found this useful link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38553/TaskScheduler)

in this they schedule trigger, and i want to Schedule my .bat file
I mean while i am trying to give my batch file path in tags textbox, its just fired trigger, not run my batch file
so, i modify that code little bit, and now I am able to run my batch file also,

but, when i close my application triggering also stop,
so, is there any way i can triggering or run my batch file even if i close my application liks window task scheduler???

kindly Help me .

Note: its desktop application using C#

Comment: Your question is not clear, but can't you just pass it in as an argument to main?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use windows task scheduler?

Comment: @Reubz this application we are make for our Employees who are not technical person, so we have to create one desktop form by which we can scheduled our batch file , and this batch file will call other console application.

Comment: @doctorlove if it possible, click on link which i mention in my question, download that project and run it.
in this project design is perfect, but i am not getting how to give path of my batch file in this project, so it will run, on scheduling.

Comment: Try posting your question on codeproject

Comment: @doctorlove ya. i already done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place the path of your batch file in **tags** textbox .Checkbox the **Active** in one time only box ,**set the time** and at that time the trigger is fired.

**Note:** It justs fire's the trigger.What you are loking is to run the batch file.In that case you need to modify the code. you can start from

```
private void buttonCreateTrigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateSchedulerItem();
    }
```

in Demo.cs page

In order to run your **batch** file or **exe** in TaskScheduler.cs find and replace this code

```
        void _triggerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _triggerTimer.Stop();
        foreach (TriggerItem item in TriggerItems)
            if (item.Enabled)
                while (item.TriggerTime <= DateTime.Now)
                    item.RunCheck(DateTime.Now);
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Your Path");
        _triggerTimer.Start();
    }
```

Now you can save this path in some knid of common class and make it access to both.

Comment: ya, when i give my batch file path in tags textbox its just fired trigger, not run my batch file.
So, i am looking for code, how to run my batch file,
i try to little bit modification in private void CreateSchedulerItem() and the event triggerItem_OnTrigger
but I didnt get solution

Comment: hey thanks for code, I just modify little bit,  
    
 `if (item.Enabled)
                    while (item.TriggerTime <= DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        item.RunCheck(DateTime.Now);
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\ST_User_1\\Desktop\\DGFTServer");
      }`   

 And, My program run perfectly!!   
 
but,its not run when I close my application like Window Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

So, what's the problem? After downloading you can check the `Demo.cs`, where you can find the method `private void CreateSchedulerItem()` and the event `triggerItem_OnTrigger`. You can change this event to run the batch file that you need.

Comment: can you tell me what type of modification I should apply??!!

Comment: I change in my coding so, now  i am able to run my batch file, according to scheduling,
but when i terminate my program it can't be scheduled,
so, is there any way to run my batch file even if I terminate my application, like window task scheduler

Comment: You just copied and pasted the code above. What did you personally try? By the way, to resolve your problem you don't need so complex program. You can resolve it by 10 lines of code. See beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. I hope that you can change `Console.WriteLine` on `System.Diagnostics`.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Timer timer = new Timer(PrintHello, autoResetEvent, 0, 5000);
    autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
}

private static void PrintHello(Object state) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```